# Slices of an ellipsoid are ellipses: Can you slice an oblate ellipsoid to get an ellipse that is more oblate?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, surfaces, ellipsoids

I'm struggling visualizing this. Is it possible to slice an ellipsoid with minor to major axis = $F$ and get an ellipse with axis ratios less than $F$?

Comment: I know adjective oblate for ellipsoids only. Please explain what it would mean for ellipses.

Comment: If $F<1$ is the ratio of the shortest axis of the ellipsoid to the longest axis, I think the answer is no, but I would try to prove it through algebra rather than visualization. By the way, I think this is true for all non-spherical ellipsoids: prolate, oblate, or three different axis lengths.

Comment: Try to find out the eccentricity using the results from my [*post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824089/intersection-spheroid-plane/2824264#2824264).

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we may assume that the major semi-axis of your ellipsoid is $1$ and minor semi-axis is $a<1$ (hence $F=a$), so we can write the equation of the ellipsoid as
$$
\tag{1}
x^2+y^2+{z^2\over a^2}=1.
$$
We are free to choose $x$ and $y$ axes such that the intersecting plane is parallel to $y$ axis.
Planes parallel to $z$ axis give rise to ellipses with axis ratio equal to $a$, hence we may ignore them.
The equation of the intersecting plane can then be written as
$$
\tag{2}
z=mx+k.
$$
The intersection between ellipsoid and plane is an ellipse, whose minor axis
is a line on $xz$ plane having the same equation $(2)$ as the plane.
The intersections $A$ and $B$ between this line and the ellipsoid can then be found plugging $y=0$ and $z=mx+k$ into $(1)$ and solving the equation for $x$.
Their $x$ coordinates are then given by
$$
x={-mk\pm\sqrt{m^2k^2-(a^2+m^2)(k^2-a^2)}\over a^2+m^2}
$$
and their $z$ coordinates can be found from $(2)$. We can then compute distance $AB$, which is the length of the minor axis of the ellipse:
$$
AB={2a\sqrt{1+m^2}\sqrt{a^2+m^2-k^2}\over a^2+m^2}.
$$
The center of the ellipse is the midpoint $M$ of $AB$:
$$
x_M=-{mk\over a^2+m^2},\quad
z_M={a^2k\over a^2+m^2}.
$$
The major axis of the ellipse is the line through $M$ parallel to $y$ axis. Its intersections with the ellipse can be found plugging $x$ and $z$ coordinates of $M$ into $(1)$ and solving for $y$:
$$
y^2={a^2+m^2-k^2\over a^2+m^2}.
$$
From that, we can find the length of major axis $CD$:
$$
CD=2{\sqrt{a^2+m^2-k^2}\over \sqrt{a^2+m^2}}.
$$
Now we can compute the desired ratio:
$$
{AB\over CD}=a{\sqrt{1+m^2}\over \sqrt{a^2+m^2}}.
$$
As $a<1$ this ratio is always greater than $a$, as it was to be proved.

[image]